Using IF Formula with VBA - VBA
I receiving an error using the below formula:
.Cells(d, LastColumn + 2).Formula = "=IF(" & .Cells(d, LastColumn + 1).Value & "<" & CDec(.Cells(9, LastColumn + 2).Value) & ",""Check"",""Do Not Check"")"

.Cells(d, LastColumn + 2).select Select the correct cell
.Cells(d, LastColumn + 1).Value = 200
CDec(.Cells(9, LastColumn + 2).Value) = 180000
Run time error 1004 - The error
Any idea what i m missing?

What are values of d  and LastColumn in error?

d = 19 & LastColumn = 148

Could you share the Excel formula for e.g. d = 11 i.e. =IF(AA?<BB?,"Check","Do Not Check")?

@VBasic2008 d = 19 formula .Cells(9, LastColumn + 2).Value

In this case I don't see any reason for Excel to produce the run time error 1004. Are you sure what does the error relate to this line of the code?

Given that you are using references relative to the Cell being edited, is there a reason not to use R1C1 notation to input the formula?  (i.e. .Cells(d, LastColumn+2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]<R9C,""Check"",""Do Not Check""))

@Chronocidal because cells will be change address dynamicly.

@Error1004 I do not understand what you mean by that — the formula I posted is dynamic with respect to Row.  It may also help if you post a complete and verifiable block of code that includes all of the variable definitions, etc, and some sample data.  Currently, no one else has been able to recreate the error, which makes debugging difficult.

You could also try adding a Debug Line for your variables immediately before the error line, e.g. Debug.Print "Variable d": Debug.Print d: Debug.Print "Variable LastColumn:": Debug.Print lastColumn: Debug.Print ".Cells(d, LastColumn + 1).Value:": Debug.Print .Cells(d, LastColumn + 1).Value: Debug.Print ".Cells(9, LastColumn + 2).Value: ": Debug.Print .Cells(9, LastColumn + 2).Value: Debug.Print "CDbl(.Cells(9, LastColumn + 2).Value)": Debug.Print CDbl(.Cells(9, LastColumn + 2).Value)

could you try adding some code for debugging:
Sub test()

    d = 19
    LastColumn = 148

    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim compareValue As Double
    
    cellValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(d, LastColumn + 1).Value
    compareValue = CDec(ActiveSheet.Cells(9, LastColumn + 2).Value)

    ActiveSheet.Cells(d, LastColumn + 2).Formula = "=IF(" & cellValue & "<" & compareValue & ",""Check"",""Do Not Check"")"

End Sub

then check the value cellvalue and comparevalue?

Since Cells(d, LastColumn + 1).Value is not cell's address, you need to perform:
.Cells(d, LastColumn + 2).Formula = Iif(.Cells(d, LastColumn + 1).Value < CDec(.Cells(9, LastColumn + 2).Value), "Check", "Do Not Check")

There is no reason to use the formula which operates with constants.

this code just import the result in the cell, I want to also show the formula.

The formula =IF(200<180000,"Check","Do Not Check") tells nothing since it's unclear which 200 and 180000 relate for.

Using below (very basic) code it works ok:

Sub test()

    d = 19
    LastColumn = 148

    ActiveSheet.Cells(d, LastColumn + 2).Formula = "=IF(" & ActiveSheet.Cells(d, LastColumn + 1).Value & "<" & CDec(ActiveSheet.Cells(9, LastColumn + 2).Value) & ",""Check"",""Do Not Check"")"

End Sub



I m receving the same error
